# make matrix mean of columns = 1

Tags: r

I need to scale a matrix such that the mean of each column is 1 to facilitate cross-factor comparisons (I'm doing nmf). I only found the scale function but I don't know how to make the mean be 1 instead of 0. Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: You could just add 1 to the scaled matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the help of `scale()`:

> If `center` is a numeric vector with length equal to the number of
>   columns of x, then each column of x has the corresponding value from
>   center subtracted from it.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame( rnorm (10 , 10 ), rnorm (10 , 5 ) )
colMeans(df)

df2 <- scale(df , center = colMeans(df)-1 , scale = FALSE )

colMeans(df)
> rnorm.10..10.  rnorm.10..5. 
>     9.626982      4.657919 
colMeans(df2)
> rnorm.10..10.  rnorm.10..5. 
>             1             1
```

Comment: or `df2 <- 1 + scale(df, scale=FALSE)` ?

Answer (score 3):

This is an underdetermined problem (there's more than one way to do it) but one possibility would be to divide each column by its mean:

```
scale(m,center=FALSE,scale=colMeans(m))
```